# Spring XD: Using log4j with logback

Tags: logback, spring-xd

I have a collection of XD job modules that all use log4j logging. I have recently upgraded to Spring XD 1.3.1 and my modules are no longer logging.

I have tried adding my packages to the xd-singlenode-logback.groovy configuration file. This has no effect. 
I have created a dummy module using slf4j, which logs correctly.

I have tried to find any information on log4j and logback compatibility, but haven't found a definitive answer.

Do I have to switch out log4j with slf4j, or is there something I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have log4j on the classpath?

xd/lib contains `log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.12.jar` which should convert your log4j calls to slf4j which in turn calls logback.

You should not have the real log4j on the CP for this to work properly, though.